# How to type this kind of data

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following kind of data

```
priceArray : any = [
    [   
        1579737600000, //open time [0]
        "8682.77000000", //open [1]
        "8691.81000000", //high [2]
        "8306.39000000", //low [3]
        "8404.52000000", //close [4]
        "48165.94459700", //volume
        1579823999999, //close time [6]
        "407428808.67533703", //quote asset volume
        464805, //number of trades
        "23287.71244400", //taker buy asset volume
        "196965082.04041370", //taker buy quote asset volume
        "0"
    ],
    [
        1579824000000,
        "8404.52000000",
        "8528.02000000",
        "8238.00000000",
        "8439.00000000",
        "41687.52952900",
        1579910399999,
        "349874174.79003938",
        407271,
        "21293.48958600",
        "178752179.11477745",
        "0"
    ],
```

Im trying to load it into a state, but i dont understand what kind of type it needs

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState<Array<Array<Number>>([])
```

The one mentioned above doesnt work

> Operator '<' cannot be applied to types '{ (initialState: S | (()
> => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction>]; <S = undefined>(): [S | undefined, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S | undefined>>]; }' and
> 'Number[][]'

Comment: It might not be the only problem, but `useState<Array<Array<Number>>` has 3 `<` and only 2 `>`

Comment: You could type it like this `const [data, setData] = useState<(string | number)[][]>([]);` or `const [data, setData] = useState<Array<Array<string|number>>>([]);`. Yes, brackets where unbalanced but also the data contains string and numbers.

Comment: But if this is your API response I wouldn't type it like this. Adding type [unknown](https://www.carlrippon.com/type-safe-data-fetching-with-unknown/) would be OK IMO and once you brought the data in the shape of your frontend I'd use typing.

Comment: @AWolf Ill take at look at the unkown type, I wasnt aware of it.